# Stop sticky scroll when at the bottom of div

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a sticky sidebar that works just like I want it to as you scroll down the main content (it sticks right where I want it), but when I get to the bottom of the page, for some reason the sidebar unsticks and keeps scrolling up, making the top several items in the sidebar menu disappear behind me fixed header.

I think this is due to the css height property that I have defined for my sticky element, which I have set at 100vh.

How can I set my sticky sidebar so that when I hit the bottom of the page, it doesn't keep scrolling up?

Here is my code for this section, and if it's easier here is a [URL](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Epneilson/LIS534/Test1/selectingbeans.html) to the working version of the site.

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
  /* sidebar styling */

aside {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 0.5;
  top: 4em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

aside a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

aside a:hover:not(.current-menu-item) {
  background-color: tan;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.current-menu-item {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* main content styling */

.content {
  margin-left: 160px;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
}

a.anchor {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  visibility: hidden;
```

```html
<section>

  <aside>
    <a class="menu-item-1" href="#target1">About</a>
    <a class="menu-item-2" href="#target2">Services</a>
    <a class="menu-item-3" href="#target3">Clients</a>
    <a class="menu-item-4" href="#target4">Contact</a>
  </aside>

  <div class="content">

    <a class="anchor" id="target1"></a>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>

    <a class="anchor" id="target2"></a>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>

    <a class="anchor" id="target3"></a>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>

    <a class="anchor" id="target4"></a>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
    <p>Text</p>

  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think this is due to the css height property that I have defined for
> my sticky element, which I have set at 100vh.

You are right. Once you scroll pass the height of the sticky element, it won't stick to the screen anymore. It is because [position sticky still sets an element in the normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

**Solution**

1. Set the height of `div.content` as same as the sticky element
2. Get rid of the default margin of `body`

This way, you don't scroll pass the height of the sticky element in the window. Therefore, the problem does not occur.

1. Right now, `div.content` has its last element overflowing with the extra padding. So, set `overflow: hidden` to keep its height same as the sticky element.
2. `body` has a default margin. So, set `margin: 0` to it.

It will fix most of the things in the right position, but there are still some unnecessary styles defined. So, you can fix the rest of it for your needs. Good luck, and I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Setting overflow:hidden on div.content stopped some of the scrolling, and then I also set the height of the <aside> sidebar element to height: calc(100vw-4em) to make up for the offset top, and now when I hit the bottom the sidebar stays put.  Thanks for the heads up on the default margin for body as well.  Were you saying that my aside or div.content or somewhere else has unnecessary styling?

Comment: I am happy that you did it..! There were many style definitions so I thought some of them might be affecting the sticky scrolling. Instead of looking at those, I just wanted to answer how position sticky works and the core solution to your problem. You will learn to clean up your code as you code more. Good luck!

Comment: The solution isn't helpful for me but upvoted for pointing out the cause of the problem.